# How to interact with UITableView in UIViewController?

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I am addicted to use TableViewController in storyboard whose class directly inherits from UITableViewController and functions like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

are there by default and you just have to implement them. But now I am using a ViewController (inherits from UIViewController) in storyboard and using a UITableView control from Object library into the view controller by drag and drop. Obviously the class I would attach to my storyboard ViewController will be inherited from UIViewController. Now how do I interact with the table cells in the UITableView control in my view controller. Want to implement same row functions above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Implement `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols in your view controller .h file.

Have an outlet for the `UITableView`.

In `viewDidLoad`, set the tableView's datasource and delegate to `self` since the viewcontroller implements the protocol.

Then, write the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. It will be getting called.

Comment: Setting the datasource and delegate to `self` in the ViewController's `viewDidLoad` isn't the cleanest way if you're using storyboards like the question asker is. If you select your `UITableView` on the storyboard and go to the connections inspector, you'll see unconnected outlets for `dataSource` and `delegate`. Ctrl-click and drag from them to the yellow circle on the left below your view controller to set the ViewController as the dataSource and delegate for the table view.

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource protocols to your table and implement it. Methods in your question are methods from these protocols and they appears automatically when you use UITableViewController.