# How to move an entire UITableView down programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview that I need to push down and resize smaller. I cannot use the content inset for this as its not the content I need to push down. I need to actually move the entire tableview down 44px.

What I have tried:

```
CGRect tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;
tableViewFrame.origin.y = 44;
self.tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with your above code?

Comment: @TheKraken Its not moving the tableview.

Comment: Is your view controller an instance of `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`?

Comment: @TheKraken UITableViewController

Comment: If it's on, Turn off ARC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change your `UITableViewController` to a regular `UIViewController` and then add the table as a subview. Then, just manually implement the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols in that view controller. After doing this, you can move the table view with your above code like any other subview.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9376032/817946) for an example.

Comment: Yeah, I ofc know how to do this. I just didn't think it was necessary.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Convert your `UITableviewController` to a `UIViewController` and then add the `tableview` as `subview` in your nib. Also don't just change the y coordinate of `tableview`. instead define a new frame for your `tableview` e.g. `self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)`

Answer (score 0):

you can not move UITableviewController down, instead of this you can do like this

1. Create a file having UIViewController subclass with XIB.(create a seperate view controller)
2. Add UITableView as subview
3. Then wired up the UITableview , delegate and datasource.
4. Implement delegate protocols for tableview
5. use your code as it is ..

it works fine.. :)