# Xcode / ObjectiveC - Convert UITableViewController into TableView embedded in a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am fairly new to this Native App dev - I have built an app which contains a UITableViewController to display messages - all works fine - but for styling reasons I need to change it from a TableViewController to a tableview embedded within a viewcontroller.

I have made a view controller containing a table view and relevant linked custom cells / fields and altered the associated header file to -

```
 @interface NotificationsListTVController : UIViewController
```

but my table methods no longer fire and I'm not sure how to instantiate them?

(code below)
    #pragma mark - Table view data source

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
return self.GPTNotifications.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
static NSString *CellIdentifierRead = @"CellRead";

UITableViewCell *cell;


notifications *n = [self.GPTNotifications objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



   if (n.read == false) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];



    CustomCellRead *cellReadB = (CustomCellRead *)cell;
    cellReadB.notifTitle.text = n.notifTitleD;
    cellReadB.notifDate.text = n.notifDateD;
    cellReadB.notifMsg.text = n.notifMessage;


 return cellReadB;
}

 else {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierRead     forIndexPath:indexPath];



    CustomCell *cellReadB = (CustomCell *)cell;
    cellReadB.notifTitle.text = n.notifTitleD;
    cellReadB.notifDate.text = n.notifDateD;
    cellReadB.notifMsg.text = n.notifMessage;


    return cellReadB;

    }


 }
```

Comment: Make sure you have set `delegate and datasource` of tableview.

Comment: See duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375903/how-to-interact-with-uitableview-in-uiviewcontroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you setting the delegate and datasource of your tableview to your class?

Something like:

```
self.myTableView.delegate = self;
self.myTableView.dataSource = self;
```

When you create a UITableViewController this is done for you, but if you add the table yourself you need to set them.

Also:

```
@interface NotificationsListTVController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way in `Interface Builder`:

- Make your `TableViewController`
- Make your `ViewController` and add a `ContainerView` to it
- Delete the segued embedded ViewController that comes with it
- Select the `ContainerView` and draw a connection from `viewDidLoad` to your `TableViewController`
- you'll get only once option: `embed`

Done. Your TableViewController will now get displayed within your ViewController.

Pass whatever Data you need forward from the ViewController to the TableViewController with the embedded Segue.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes in NotificationsListTVController.h:

```
@interface NotificationsListTVController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

Also in NotificationsListTVController.m, dont forget to provide these two statements as well.

```
 tableView.delegate=self ;
 tableView.dataSource=self;
```

These are required to set the delegate methods.These two statements need to be provided after initializing your tableView. Like for instance :

```
   tblView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,200,320,420) style: UITableViewStyleGrouped];


   tblView.delegate = self;
   tblView.dataSource = self;

   [self.view addSubview:tblView];
```

These methods you are referring to are the delegate methods which cannot be fired directly unlike other ordinary methods.

Hope it Helps!!!