# UITableView needed alongside UIViewController

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller

In order for table to load fast, need something like this, because the `TableView` is inside a `UIViewController`:

```
ViewController: UITableViewController, UIViewcontroller UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
```

But I get this error `NSInternalInconsistencyException`, reason:

> [UITableViewController loadView] loaded the
>   "nbc-Kp-sp6-view-lBB-IH-x0z" nib but didn't get a UITableView.' This
>   is because it is a UIViewController.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to interact with UITableView in UIViewController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375903/how-to-interact-with-uitableview-in-uiviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get inherited from two controllers. You should probably delete getting inheritance from `UITableViewController`. Instead, use a `UITableView` alongside in your **xib** file(or you are using **storyboard**?). Then, connect to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` just like the normal way you do when you handle `UITableViewController`.

Should be something like:

```
ViewController:UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableViewController!

    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate 
    ...
}
```