# Objective C Connect UITableViewController with UITableview programmatically or using dashboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to objective c. I have an UIView and i am adding programmatically an UITableView. I have an UIViewController but i do not want to use it to manipulate and show the data to the UITableView. I created a subclass of UITableViewController to manipulate the data and show them to the UITableView. I am trying to understand how to connect my Custom UITableViewController to the UITableView either programmatically or by using the storyboard.

Is the above scenario possible?

The only way i can do it is using an UITableViewController directly from the storyboard.

Comment: A `UITableViewController` has is **own** table view. You have a couple options: 1) have your view controller conform to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`; 2) Write a separate class that conforms to them; 3) Load a `UITableViewController` as a **child** view controller and add its table view to your view hierarchy.

Comment: Just create an objet which implements UITableView dataSource and delegate!and set is as delegate and dataSource of the tableView.

Comment: 2) Write a separate class that conforms to them; The UItableViewController subclass does not conform to UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate?

Comment: @stefanosn - I think the first question you need to answer is: ***Why*** do you want your table view handling separated from your view controller? Since there are multiple ways to approach it, we need to know what your goal is.

Comment: @Donmag Trying to achieve Model-View-Controller design...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to interact with UITableView in UIViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375903/how-to-interact-with-uitableview-in-uiviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

In general, table view DataSource and Delegate methods are already pretty well segmented into the MVC design pattern.

You might want to head over to google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `model view controller design pattern with uitableview`. Plenty of articles / blogs / examples / discussions / etc that are probably good to read through first.

You also may find that using an Objective-C `Category` would be a better approach.

However, here is a very, very simple example of using a separate class as your table view's DataSource and Delegate:

**MyTableHandler.h**

```
//  MyTableHandler.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyTableHandler : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@end
```

**MyTableHandler.m**

```
//  MyTableHandler.m

#import "MyTableHandler.h"

@implementation MyTableHandler

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *c = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row: %ld", indexPath.row];
    c.textLabel.text = s;
    return c;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Row %ld selected!", (long)indexPath.row);
    // How do we tell the VIEW CONTROLLER the row was selected?
    // We have to use either protocol / delegate pattern, or
    //  we have to pass Blocks
}

@end
```

**MyViewController.h**

```
//  MyViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

**MyViewController.m**

```
//  MyViewController.m

#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "MyTableHandler.h"

@interface MyViewController ()
{
    UITableView *tableView;
    MyTableHandler *myTableHandler;
}
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemYellowColor];
    
    tableView = [UITableView new];
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
    
    UILayoutGuide *g = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        
        // constrain tableView 80-pts from top (safe area)
        //  20-pts leading / trailing / bottom (safe area)
        [tableView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:80.0],
        [tableView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor constant:20.0],
        [tableView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant:-20.0],
        [tableView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.bottomAnchor constant:-20.0],
        
    ]];

    [tableView registerClass:UITableViewCell.class forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    
    // instantiate MyTableHandler
    myTableHandler = [MyTableHandler new];
    tableView.dataSource = myTableHandler;
    tableView.delegate = myTableHandler;
    
}

@end
```